gzip.open in wt mode results in an invalid archive
I am writing a program that predicts certain sequences. I want it to save the results in a gzipped fasta format. However, when trying to write to such a file I am getting an invalid file (when trying to open it on Windows I get compressed archive folders error). This is the relevant code:
def annotate_fasta_file(model, input_path, output_path):
    """
    Annotates all sequences in a FASTA file with CpG island predictions.

    Parameters:
        model (object): A trained classifier model.
        input_path (str): Path to the input FASTA file.
        output_path (str): Path to the output FASTA file where annotations will be saved.

    Writes:
        A gzipped FASTA file containing predicted annotations for each input sequence.
    """

    sequences = parse_fasta_file(input_path)    
    with gzip.open(output_path, 'wt') as gzipped_file:
        for seq_id, sequence in sequences.items():
            annotation = annotate_sequence(model, sequence)
            gzipped_file.write(f">{seq_id}\n{annotation}\n")

This is the error I get when trying to click or extract the output file:
enter image description here

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Are you sure you want a gzip file, not a zip file?

gzip files are just compressed, they're not archives like zip files or .tar.gz files.

This is a requrement of my excersise...

Are you expected to be able to open the resulting file on standard Windows? If you have WSL, you can page through it with gunzip < out.fa.gz | less. There’s also third-party software like 7-Zip.

This file format is used as a compression format for Linux and Unix operating systems. In Windows you can use programs like WinZip or WinRAR to open and decompress your GZ files.

Thank you I didn't know that. It does work on wsl, and I got input files in the same format (at least the signature is the same) which I could open on windows for some reason...
